# Extract parts from Outlook email subject and then find it in an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have an email subject that looks like this: 
`RE: Blah blah - Blah blah, 1234-56, Blah blah blah`

I was wondering how to extract `1234-56` from the email subject.

I tried:

```
If myemail.Subject Like "****-**" Then
```

But that only gives me true/false and I want the actual data, `1234-56`.

Additionally, I was hoping to use the find function on my spreadsheet to find where the data is located.

So for example, since the email subject contains `1234-56`, I will go on my spreadsheet and use the find function to find `1234-56`.

I tried:

```
Cells.Find( _
    What := myemail.Subject, _
    After := ActiveCell, _
    LookIn := xlValues, _
    LookAt := xlPart, _
    SearchOrder := xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection := xlNext, _
    MatchCase := False, _
    SearchFormat := False).Activate
```

But I don't think that's the correct syntax.
Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Regular Expressions for this task. Here is an example which shows how you can find a pattern like `####-##` (four digits, dash, two digits) in a random string.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub RegEx()
    'this is your subject
    Const Subject As String = "RE: Blah blah - Blah blah, 1234-56, Blah blah blah"

    Dim objRegEx As Object
    Set objRegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    With objRegEx
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .Pattern = "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}" 'this is the pattern to find ####-## where # is a number from 0-9

        Dim objMatches As Object
        Set objMatches = .Execute(Subject)
    End With

    'print all matches in the intermediate window
    Dim objMatch As Object
    For Each objMatch In objMatches
        Debug.Print objMatch
    Next
End Sub
```

To test and build patterns you can easily use [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/dnC7sg/2)

Comment: Thank you for your help! And thanks for sharing the regex function, will definitely keep it in mind for future use.